# Prove that $0 \le a \mod b \lt b$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I want to prove that $0 \le a \mod b \lt b$ if a,b are integers and b is positive.
I have tried to prove that $0 \le a \mod b$ already.
First, I used
$$a \mod b = a - \lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor \times b$$
Second, I substitute $\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor$ with $\lfloor N + \frac{c}{b} \rfloor$, where N,c are integers and $0 \le c \lt b$

Now, I have got
$$\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor = N$$ 
We have the condition that
$$\frac{a}{b} - 1 \lt N \le \frac{a}{b}$$
Then,
$$0 \le a - Nb \lt 2a - b$$
From the above equation, $a - Nb = a \mod b$

Now, I have $0 \le a \mod b$ already. Can anyone can complete my proof?

Comment: Why don't you use the definition of mod as finding the reminders?

Comment: How do you use inequality sign **with** modular arithmetic ? What in fact the inequality $\;a\pmod b<b\;$ means *at all*?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think the OP means $a\bmod b$ (the operator), and not $a\mod b$ (the binary relation).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean the operator as @Bernard explained.

Comment: @GGG:For the operator, the LaTeX command is `\bmod`.

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure I understand what's the difference and also what does "binary relation" mean in this context: for me, $\;a\pmod b\;$ means the residue (usually, but *not a fortior*, non-negative and less than $\;b\;$) we get when dividing $\;a\;$ by $\;b\;$ . Is there *any* other meaning?

Comment: The binary relation is congruence : $a\equiv a'\mod b$ (also denoted $a\equiv a'\pmod b$), while the remainder is $r=a\bmod b$ (note the smaller space between $a$ and $\bmod$).

Comment: @Bernard Again, what's *the difference* between the two?  I don't care too much whether it is $\;7=2\pmod 5\;$ or $\;7\equiv 2\pmod 5\;$ . For me, both mean that **in the integers** , $\;7-2=5\;$ is divisible by $\;5\;$ . Is there any **other** meaning than this one?

Comment: There's no other meaning, but $7 \bmod5$ denotes a *number* , while $7\equiv 12\mod5$ is an *assertion* (‘$7$ and $12$ have the same remainder’)..

Comment: @Bernard This is weird and I can't see how it relates to your first comment of binary relation against operator (?), yet the OP agreed with you, but then: what's the question here? That we can choose a complete set of representative for the equivalence relation $\;\bmod b\;$ which are integers between zero and $\;b-1\;$ ? This is trivial and known from elementary school..but it **does not need to be so**: there can also be negative representatives or arbitrarily large positive ones, and thus larger than $\;b\;$ ....

Comment: Yes but the remainder is in$[0,b)$, and it is this remainder which is denoted $a\bmod b$ in computer software.

Comment: @Bernard You mean "the remainder" in the sense of basic division in elementary school, right? Because I can't remember any such requirement from "the remainder" in ring theory or number theory, and you can see this, for instance, in examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder . Perhaps that is so in computer science, but (1) this is a mathematics site, and (2) there was no tagging mentioning computers at all. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question was a very simple question about integers, and I answered this particular question. I know that in more general contexts, the remainder is not necessarily unique, but in many situations, it *is* unique, by means of supplementary conditions (cf *Euclidean stathms* or *Gröbner bases*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By def., $$\left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor :=N \leq \frac{a}{b} \leq \left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor +1 =N+1.$$
Then from the left half, $a \geq Nb$ for $b >0$ as assumed, and so $$a-Nb =a \;\; (\textrm{mod}\; b) \geq 0.$$
And from the right half, $a \leq Nb+b$, or $$a-Nb =a \;\; (\textrm{mod}\; b) \leq b,$$
as desired.